# How to bring currentview of iCarousel to the top of other views in iCarouselTypeWheel

Tags: ios, icarousel

I want to create a wheel similar to "http://www.asianpaints.com/royale" in iOS, till now I have used `iCarousel` type: `iCarouselTypeWheel`. It almost works for me but main problem is the center view got overlapped by next elements. Please let me know how to fix.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will actually need to change the z transform value (that is returning) of `CATransform3DTranslate` function in `transformForItemViewWithOffset` method. This is kind of hacky though.

To do this,

- Open your `iCarousel.m` file
- Look for `-(CATransform3D)transformForItemViewWithOffset:(CGFloat)offset` method
- Inside the `switch case` statement, go to `iCarouselTypeWheel` and in the else part, you will need to change the line

  ```
  return CATransform3DTranslate(transform, 0.0f, -radius, offset * 0.01f);
  ```

  to

  ```
  return CATransform3DTranslate(transform, 0.0f, -radius, 0.0f);
  ```

Save the file and run the project to see if that gives you the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Standard wheel set "first" element on most left or most right position, so if you want to carousel begins in top you need set carousel type to `iCarouselTypeCustom` and provide transform in  `carousel:itemTransformForOffset:baseTransform:` you can take transform from iCarousel source as base

Comment: This is actually the correct answer. Don't hack the library - use the delegate to provide a custom transform, and copy the transform logic from the standard wheel implementation.

Comment: Yes That is what I have Done.. using iCarouselTypeCustom Type and implemented the logic. Thanks Nick For the great library.